# location services settings enable through code javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, geolocation, location, settings

I have implemented Geo-Location based Mobile Websites.It will retrieve the user location  if the **location services** > **on**.

**OFF Condition**

If no geo capabilities are present or disabled it will display message  `Enable locations services for Better Experience`

It is possible to **enable** location services through code Or Simply Opening location Services setting [**page**] from the application.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This would be a big security issue if you could do this, so as for enabling location services through code, the the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks.It is possible to open location services settings page through my code @Andy